# Supplying an authentication token via HTTPComponents library

Tags: java, httpclient, restful-authentication

I am using the [HTTPComponents library](http://hc.apache.org/) for this implementation.

My RESTful implementation comprises of supplying a username/password, to generate a token. This token, in turn is supplied as a header to the ensuing API calls as:

```
authorization = <40 char token>
```

However, a  `method.addRequestHeader("authorization","<40 char token>");` isn't authenticating the service call.

Do I need to specify the token differently?

Comment: Use Google Developer Tools or a REST client to inspect the request being sent. Might be helpful to include that request, as well as your processing code, in the question.

Comment: the format above works perfectly when i use firefox's poster. so the problem is programmitically supplying the authentication. the url is specified as a string, as is the request header per the command above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is acceptable method to pass token in httpheader.
but try to send token after encoding on network for more secure transmission.